# Fix a percentage calculator in c?

Tags: c, percentage, percentile

I've tried using this code but the console crashes after the user inputs the total score

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    int part, total;
    int whole = 100;
    printf("What is total score of the exam?\n");
    scanf("%d", part);
    printf("Enter your score on the exam\n");
    scanf("%d", total);
    printf(total/part * whole);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the format string for that last `printf()`?

Comment: You need to a) start reading the manuals, and b) enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: The second parameter of scanf() has to be a *pointer to the variable* you want to read the value into, not just the value of the variable. For example `scanf("%d", &part);` instead of `scanf("%d", part);`.

Answer (score 3):

A short answer so this question does not stay unanswered. You should enable compiler warnings and learn to interpret them, so you can solve problems by yourself more easily. On GCC you can add the `-Wall` compiler option to display the usual warnings you need to see such problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int part, total;
    int whole = 100;

    printf("What is total score of the exam?\n");
    scanf("%d", &part); /* address of part needed, not its value*/

    printf("Enter your score on the exam\n");
    scanf("%d", &total); /* address of total needed, not its value*/

    printf("%d", total/part * whole); /* printf expects a string as its first parameter */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in @Striezel's comment, you need to add a pointer to the second parameter in a `scanf`, so you're not just retrieving the value of the variable, but pointing to the variable that you want to read into.

Your `scanf` code should look like this:

```
int main() {
    ...
    scanf("%d", &part);
    ...
    scanf("%d", &total);
    ...
}
```

Also, your last `printf` is missing a string component, which would look like this in full: `printf("%d", total/part * whole);`

Also take a look at @LudaOtaku's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814039/6728196) for some tips on recognizing these very basic errors.

Comment: You should also provide the fix for the broken `printf` call.

Comment: @LudaOtaku Was adding that in. Thanks for heads up though